# Is there a way got get a seekbar to get values from textview?

Tags: android, seekbar

What i'm want to do is this ! I have one text view with a a total budget inserted by the user, and another textview with the sum of expenses. 
Is there anyway to get the seekbar max value to get textview1 value and increase acording to the total value on textview2?

If i shouldn't use seekbar for this please point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a TextChangedListener to your EditText using Integer.parseInt on the Editable to setMax(int) of your SeekBar. For setting the interval you would want to round your the amount the user has sought to your the nearest interval value after getting it from your second EditText...

```
EditText etMaxValue, etInterval;
SeekBar seekBar;

int interval = 1;

public IntervalSeekBar() {

    //Initialize your EditText and SeekBar objects...

    etMaxValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
            seekBar.setMax(Integer.parseInt(text.toString()));
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}           
    });

    etInterval.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
            interval = Integer.parseInt(text.toString());
            if (interval < 1) { interval = 1; }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}           
    });

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar sb, int value, boolean userInitiated) {
            value = ((int) Math.round(value/interval)) * interval;
            seekBar.setProgress(value);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) { }
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}
    });
}
```